# Net flow out of $x$ equals net flow into $y$

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Let $D=(V, A)$ be a digraph and $f$ a real-valued function on $A$.

I am trying to show:

1. $\sum\left\{f^{+}(v): v \in V\right\}=\sum\left\{f^{-}(v): v \in V\right\}$,
2. if $f$ is an $(x, y)$-flow, then the net flow $f^{+}(x)-f^{-}(x)$ out of $x$ is equal flow $f^{-}(y)-f^{+}(y)$ into $y$.

**My attempt:**

I don't know how to do the first part, but for the second part I have the following

\begin{aligned}
0=& f(V, V)-f(V, V) \\
=& {[f(x, V)+f(y, V)]-[f(V, x)+f(V, y)]} \\
&+\sum_{v \neq x, y}(f(v, V)-f(V, v)) \\
=& {[f(x, V)+f(y, V)]-[f(V, x)+f(V, y)] }
\end{aligned}

Note:
$f(x, V)$ is the same as $f^{+}(x)$ (flow from $x$ to another vertex) and $f(V, x)$ is the same as $f^{-}(x)$ (flow from another vertex to $x$), and $f(x, V)$-$f(V, x)$ is the net flow out of $x$

Comment: In the introduction it seems that $f$ is a function defined on the vertices of your digraph, but then you work with $f$ as if it takes two inputs. Perhaps you can clarify.

Comment: @SammyBlack Clarified